# Bitbucket pipeline failing while building docker-compose command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines

```
  image: python:3.7.4-alpine3.10

  pipelines:
    tags:
      ecr-release-*:
        - step:
            services:
              - docker
            caches:
              - pip
            script:
              - pip3 install awscli
              - pip3 install docker
              - pip3 install docker-compose
              - IMAGE="983344321808.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cicd"
              - TAG=${BITBUCKET_BRANCH:-$BITBUCKET_TAG}
              - aws configure set aws_access_key_id "AKIA6J47DSUIAZH466UH"
              - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "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"
              - eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | sed 's;https://;;g')
              - docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build
              # - docker push $IMAGE:$TAG
```

Here is my bitcucket-pipeline yaml file.
I an trying to build image using docker-compose command
But, It is getting failed without showing any error,

Please check the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure that you refreshed the page and scrolled to the very bottom of it? Pipelines UI sometimes trims the output of the step, and page refresh usually remediates that.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly affected by this bug
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-20351

A workaround is to download the raw logs file or to fetch them via API.